# PHP - take element from array and push it at the beginning

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simple way to take specific array element, and place it at the beginning of the array?

For example I have this array:

```
$array = [

    [
        'name' => 'Jon Doe',
        'age'  => 44,
        'sex'  => 'm'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Joana Doe',
        'age'  => 44,
        'sex'  => 'f'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jon Doe',
        'age'  => 44,
        'sex'  => 'm'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Some Name',
        'age'  => 44,
        'sex'  => 'f'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Another Name',
        'age'  => 44,
        'sex'  => 'f'
    ],


];
```

and I want to take array where **name** is **Some Name**, and place it at the beginning  of the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search by value and reindex the array, then something like that should do.

```
function searchForId($name, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['name'] === $name) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
$id = searchForId('name', $array);
if($id !== null) {
   $tmp = $array[$id];
   unset($array[$id]);
   $array = array_values($array);
   array_unshift($array, $tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Simple element swapping.

```
$tmp = $array[2]; // 3rd element
$array[2] = $array[0]; // set 3rd to values with 1st
$array[0] = $tmp; // set first to values with 3rd
```

Comment: I'd assume they want to keep the order of the rest of the elements, so effectively "move them all up" by one index ...